# How do I get the code to only look at certain parameters in the column?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 columns (category, sumoftotal, case level suggestion). Goal is to have Case level calculated with IIF statement based on certain parameters. I have the code to work based on the parameters. However, I want to apply the current parameters to category with the term trays and have another code set with different parameters applied to category with the term equipment.(Trays and Equipment are in the same column). How do I get the code to looks at only trays in the category column apply the IIF and add another similar IFF to look at only equipment in the category column.

Current code is:

```
SELECT [Calculated Total].casemain_id, [Calculated Total].category, 
Sum([Calculated Total].Total) AS SumOfTotal, IIf([SumOfTotal] <=3,
"A",IIf([SumOfTotal]>=9,"D",IIf([SumOfTotal]>=6,"C",IIf([SumOfTotal]       
>=4,"B","C")))) AS [Case Level Suggested]
FROM [Calculated Total]
GROUP BY [Calculated Total].casemain_id, [Calculated Total].category
ORDER BY [Calculated Total].casemain_id;
```

I have been trying to add  WHERE [Calculated Total].category='Instrument Trays'; but keep getting an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `WHERE`, you need to use `HAVING` when you are grouping in a query:

```
SELECT C.casemain_id, C.category,Sum([C].Total) AS SumOfTotal, 
IIf([SumOfTotal] <=3,
"A",IIf([SumOfTotal]>=9,"D",IIf([SumOfTotal]>=6,"C",IIf([SumOfTotal]       
>=4,"B","C")))) AS [Case Level Suggested]
FROM [Calculated Total] AS C
GROUP BY C.casemain_id, C.category
HAVING C.category="Instrument Trays"
ORDER BY C.casemain_id
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks again! This worked and I was able to use UNION to set the other parameters. It works perfect!